# Parse feet and inches formatted string and convert to inches as a floating point value

Tags: php, math, data-conversion, text-parsing, units-of-measurement

In my database, there is a field called `height` that is a `varchar(9)` field.  The end user selects a value from a pull-down list that contains values such as:

5' 0
5' 0 1/2
5' 1
5' 1 1/2
5' 2
5' 2 1/2
And so on up to...
7' 4

What I need to do is convert this string into numeric inches for the purpose of a server-side calculation. How can this be done?

Comment: Multiply the feet by twelve, and add the remaining inches.  The reason you haven't found copy/paste code for this is that the answer is obvious.

Comment: That's basic math. 1 foot = 12 inches

Comment: One technique would be to use `explode("'", $height)` to get an array that contains the feet in the first element, and the inches in the second element.  Then use an explode on the inches, to watch for halves.  Do your math, and away you go.

Comment: The question isn't a math question, people.  It's how to parse the string.

Comment: @cale_b: Well, that's what he should have asked, then.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Agreed.  But the comments don't even attempt to address that, they just aggravate the situation.

Comment: How are you populating the dropdown?

Comment: @cale_b: Post a real answer, then.

Comment: From the "Help" section - `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.` - Please tell us what you've tried already and why you think it didn't work. I think it would be better for everyone if you tried solving the problem yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to get separate variables for feet, inches and fraction first

```
$toBeConverted = "5' 4 1/2";
list($feet,$inches,$frac) = explode(' ',$toBeConverted . ' ');
```

then add those values

```
$total = ((str_replace("'",'',$feet) * 12) + $inches + ($frac == '1/2' ? (1/2) : 0));
```

Comment: I like the use of `list`. Very nice. But note that there is a `'` after the `feet`.

Comment: thanks. and oh, that code would have generated a notice if there is no fraction, hence the `. ' '` after `$toBeConverted`. additional keys in the array won't generate notices

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of the pulldown, with the first value being 0, then the number of inches is

```
$inches = 60 + $pulldownIndex * 0.5;
```

Since you start at `5'` (5 * 12 = 60) and go up in increments of 0.5 inch.

Alternately, if you want to look at the string that was on the pulldown, I suggest you look at Felix's answer - it is very compact and elegant.

Comment: Really elegant answer

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - yes; Dmitry's comment was for my original one-line answer. I updated with complete code later, but your solution is far more elegant. I have deleted my "long" answer and refer to yours instead - I think my "short" answer is still quite useful though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$inches=0;
$array=explode(" ",$string);//where $string is "5' 0 1/2" for example
if ($array[2]='1/2') $inches=(int)$array[0]*12+(int)$array[1]+0.5;
    else $inches=(int)$array[0]*12+(int)$array[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf()` is most definitely the cleanest tool for parsing your formatted strings.  It is better than `preg_match()` because it doesn't create an unnneeded fullstring match AND it can parse all substrings to integers.

In the same family of `sscanf()`, `printf()` is an ideal way to present your result truncated to a specified number of decimal places and write additional text (such as `inches`) next to the float value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BZaoS))

```
$tests = [
    "5'",
    "5' 0",
    "5' 0 1/2",
    "5' 1",
    "5' 1 1/2",
    "5' 2",
    "5' 2 1/2",
    "7' 4",
];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    sscanf($test, '%d\' %d %d/%d"', $feet, $inches, $numerator, $denominator);
    printf("%.1f\n", ($feet * 12) + $inches + ($denominator ? $numerator / $denominator : 0));
}
```

Output:

```
60.0
60.0
60.5
61.5
61.5
62.5
62.5
88.5
```